# Returning a value before committing transaction and (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, transactions

I need to check if a record exists - if yes: then returns its id, if not: creates a new record and returns its id. I am using `WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)` in `SELECT` to prevent from duplicates (it creates lock). I wonder if I should commit the transaction if a record exists in a database for realising the lock?

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("..."))
{
    await connection.OpenAsync();
    using (var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
    {
        var locationId = await connection.QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<int?>(
                "SELECT id 
                 FROM Locations WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)
                 WHERE regionId = @RegionId", new { RegionId = 1 }, transaction: transaction
            );

        if (locationId.HasValue)
        {
            //transaction.Commit(); // should I commit the transaction here?
            return locationId.Value;
        }

        var location = new Location()
        {
            Name = "test",
            RegionId = 1
        };

        var newLocationid = await connection.InsertAsync<int>(location, transaction);

        transaction.Commit();

        return newLocationid;                    
    }
}
```

Comment: @Charlieface without (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK) I get duplicates in my database because I don't have an unique index on the regionId column.

Comment: Maybe remove the lock hints and just use a unique constraint to prevent duplicates?

Comment: @Stu it isn't so simple to remove duplicates :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> should I commit the transaction here?

Yes.  Otherwise it will roll back when the using block completes.  That won’t matter in this particular case, but it’s better to be explicit.  And if this transaction was part of a larger transaction, the whole thing would get rolled back.

Answer (score -1):

You do not need a transaction here.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("..."))
{
    await connection.OpenAsync();
    /* The lock hints you had here makes no sense. */
    var locationId = await connection.QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<int?>(
            "SELECT id 
             FROM Locations
             WHERE regionId = @RegionId", new { RegionId = 1 }
        );

    if (locationId.HasValue)
    {
        return locationId.Value;
    }

    var location = new Location()
    {
        Name = "test",
        RegionId = 1
    };

    /* INSERT has an implicit transaction 
       only need to use a transaction if you have multiple DML statements (i.e. INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statments) */
    var newLocationid = await connection.InsertAsync<int>(location);
    return newLocationid;                    
}
```

}

Comment: without (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK) I get duplicates in my database because I don't have an unique index on the regionId column.

Answer (score -2):

Well you don't have to begin transaction while querying. You can rewrite your code as below:

```
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("..."))
    {
        await connection.OpenAsync();
        var locationId = await connection.QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<int?>(
                    "SELECT id 
                     FROM Locations WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)
                     WHERE regionId = @RegionId", new { RegionId = 1 });
    
        if (locationId.HasValue)
        {
            return locationId.Value;
        }
    
        using (var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
        {
            var location = new Location()
            {
                Name = "test",
                RegionId = 1
            };
    
            var newLocationid = await connection.InsertAsync<int>(location, transaction);
    
            transaction.Commit();
        }

        return newLocationid;
    }
```

Comment: WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK) needs a transaction